# How to reference a VueUse useFirestore ref in another useFirestore?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vueuse

I'm trying to use the VueUse [useFirestore()](https://vueuse.org/firebase/usefirestore/) wrapper.

It returns a ref that is in sync with a Firestore document.

Currently I can use it to get and display a `users` doc.

But now I need to get and display a `websites` doc by referencing a `currentWebsiteId` field from the `users` doc.

When I try to do that, nothing is displayed. There are no errors in the console either.

This is what my code looks like:

```Vue
<template>
  <div>{{ user }}</div> 
  <div>{{ website }}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useAuth } from '@vueuse/firebase/useAuth';
import { useFirestore } from '@vueuse/firebase/useFirestore';
import { doc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { auth, db } from 'src/config/firebase';
import { User, Website } from 'src/types';

const { user: authUser } = useAuth(auth);

const userDocRef = doc(db, `users/${authUser.value?.uid}`);
const user = useFirestore<User>(userDocRef);

const websiteDocRef = doc(db, `websites/${user.value?.currentWebsiteId}`);
const website = useFirestore<Website>(websiteDocRef);
</script>
```

Since `useFirestore()` is asynchronous it will initially return `undefined` before shortly after returning the actual Firestore document.

I thought this could be the issue, so I tried using a `watch` to get around that like so:

```TypeScript
let website = ref();
watch(user, () => {
  const websiteDocRef = doc(db, `websites/${user.value?.currentWebsiteId}`);
  website = useFirestore<Website>(websiteDocRef);
});
```

But that also has the same problem. Nothing is nothing is displayed, and there are no errors in the console either.

Comment: `  website = useFirestore` - this is a mistake, never reassign refs, only their values. Composables are supposed to be used directly in setup, by calling it multiple times you most likely misuse it. Wrap `doc()` that depends on currentWebsiteId with a computed. It's already explained in docs, https://vueuse.org/firebase/usefirestore/#usage

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, this worked. Do you want to turn this comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @EstusFlask I have a very similar follow up question if you wouldn't mind looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73715248/how-to-use-vueuse-usefirestore-with-a-where-queryconstraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @EstusFlask, [the docs show](https://vueuse.org/firebase/usefirestore/#usage) that it needs to be wrapped in a `computed` ref.

This is because `computed` gets recalculated when any of it's ref values change.

Therefore `websiteDocRef` becomes this:

```Vue
const websiteDocRef = computed(() =>
  doc(db, `websites/${user.value?.currentWebsiteId}`)
);
```

Here is the full code:

```Vue
<template>
  <div>{{ user }}</div> 
  <div>{{ website }}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useAuth } from '@vueuse/firebase/useAuth';
import { useFirestore } from '@vueuse/firebase/useFirestore';
import { doc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { auth, db } from 'src/config/firebase';
import { User, Website } from 'src/types';

const { user: authUser } = useAuth(auth);

const userDocRef = doc(db, `users/${authUser.value?.uid}`);
const user = useFirestore<User>(userDocRef);

const websiteDocRef = computed(() =>
  doc(db, `websites/${user.value?.currentWebsiteId}`)
);
const website = useFirestore<Website>(websiteDocRef);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

As commented by @Estus Flask,  `website = useFirestore` - this is a mistake, never reassign refs, only their values. Composables are supposed to be used directly in setup, by calling it multiple times you most likely misuse it. Wrap `doc()` that depends on `currentWebsiteId` with a computed. It's already explained in docs, vueuse.org/firebase/usefirestore/#usage

Comment: This is just a copy and paste of the comment made by @EstusFlask. For a better answer next time please provide code to demonstrate your answer. It helps everyone who may read this.

Comment: @TinyTiger I shared this comment as a solution for community purpose, so it would help if anyone is facing same issue. And as I have little knowledge on `vue.js` I just shared EstusFlask comment.will take care of this in my next answers. Thanks for the feedback.