# How to use VueUse useFirestore() with a Where QueryConstraint?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vueuse

I have a Firestore `users` doc that looks something like this:

```TypeScript
{
    currentCompanyId: "123",
    displayName: "Mary Jane" 
}
```

And a Firestore `websites` doc that looks something like this:

```TypeScript
{
    companyId: "123",
    homePageUrl: "https://www.google.com/"
}
```

Now I'm trying to use the VueUse [useFirestore()](https://vueuse.org/firebase/usefirestore/) wrapper to display the `websites` doc.

To do that I am referencing the `currentCompanyId` property of the `users` doc inside a `where` Query Constraint like so:

```TypeScript
<template>
  <div>
    {{ websites?.[0] }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useAuth } from '@vueuse/firebase/useAuth';
import { useFirestore } from '@vueuse/firebase/useFirestore';
import { collection, doc, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { auth, db } from 'src/config/firebase';
import { User } from 'src/types';
import { computed } from 'vue';

const { user: authUser } = useAuth(auth);
const userDocRef = doc(db, `users/${authUser.value?.uid}`);
const user = useFirestore<User>(userDocRef);

const websiteQuery = computed(() =>
  query(
    collection(db, 'websites'),
    where('companyId', '==', user.value?.currentCompanyId) // This produces an error
    // where('companyId', '==', '123') // This works, but is not practical
  )
);
const websites = useFirestore(websiteQuery);
</script>
```

Hard-coding the `companyId` value of `123` works.

But whenever I use `user.value?.currentCompanyId` inside the computed ref it throws an error saying this:

> TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was that `user.value?.currentCompanyId` is initially `null`.

Here is the error message again:

> TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got null

It's basically saying the right-hand side of the `Where` query constraint should be an object, but it got null.

Wrapping the query in a `computed` ref will eventually change the value from `null` into something else when it updates. But initially it is `null`. And that is the cause of the error.

To overcome this problem you can set some initial properties of `user` in the `useFirestore`. So the `Where` query constraint will use that non-null value initially. Even an empty string will be ok. You can use anything that is not `null`.

Here is the full code:

```Vue
<template>
  <div>
    {{ websites?.[0] }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useAuth } from '@vueuse/firebase/useAuth';
import { useFirestore } from '@vueuse/firebase/useFirestore';
import { collection, doc, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { auth, db } from 'src/config/firebase';
import { User } from 'src/types';
import { computed } from 'vue';

const { user: authUser } = useAuth(auth);
const userDocRef = doc(db, `users/${authUser.value?.uid}`);
const user = useFirestore<User>(userDocRef, { currentCompanyId: '' }); // <-- See change here

const websiteQuery = computed(() =>
  query(
    collection(db, 'websites'),
    where('companyId', '==', user.value?.currentCompanyId)
  )
);
const websites = useFirestore(websiteQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the `QueryConstraint` only when the value is defined like this:

```
const websiteQuery = computed(() => {
  const queryContraints: any = [];
  const currentCompanyId = user.value?.currentCompanyId;

  if (currentCompanyId) queryContraints.push(where("companyId", "==", currentCompanyId));
  return query(
    collection(db, 'websites'),
    ...queryContraints
  )
});
```

This however will return all documents if you don't provide the `where()` constraint so maybe try running query only when this is defined i.e. after the auth state has loaded. `onAuthStateChanged()` might be useful here.

Comment: Thanks this works, and I am already ensuring the auth state has loaded when the app starts so that is not an issue. I have also noticed that I can use Template Literals (back ticks) for the value like this `\`${user.value?.currentCompanyId}\`` and it works. Can you shed light on why that works? I thought an empty template literal would be `undefined` and therefore also throw an error, but that does not happen.

Comment: @TinyTiger when you use template literals, the result will be `"undefined"` (as string) so that is a valid value. It'll search for docs where `companyId` is `"undefined"` (string). But `undefined` is not  a valid value.